# Actors do not replicate when using sessions | Unreal engine 4.7.5

Tags: unreal-engine4

I have followed the Multiplayer Shootout showcase (https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Resources/Showcases/BlueprintMultiplayer/index.html) and tried to replicate the sessions part for my own project. I can create a (LAN) session, see other sessions and join one. My problem is that, for some reason, the correct map opens, but the actors do not replicate. If I simply open the map, for 2 players, they replicate without any issues. Is there something else I should do to enable replications when using sessions? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further testing the program, it gave me the following error:LogNet:Warning: Travel Failure: [LoadMapFailure]: Failed to load package '/Game/Maps/UEDPIE_2_Arena2'. Which I found out was because I was testing the game sessions inside the editor. After I tried testing it in Standalone Game mode, everything was working fine.